# How to combine using Membership API with own application related data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

Designing a new application in asp.net 4 I have to make a decision how to use a MS SQL Membership API along with my own data in the MS SQL data base. Firstly I need to store and access user profile data in more flexible manner then the Profile provider supports. Secondly I would like to link other user related information (e.g. Orders).

No matter where you store your aspnetdb tables (in the separate data base or in the same data base with your data), the problem stays how to keep your data synchronized.

After a research I see the following relevant options:
1. Foreign key UserId from asp_Users (suggested in [this](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs) tutorial).
2. No foreign key - use transactions (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938266/when-using-asp-net-membership-plus-an-additional-table-to-store-user-information)).
3. No foreign key - use customized AccountController (whatever it is, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348173/how-would-you-use-entity-framework-1-0-with-asp-net-membership)).
4. Additional table which links Membership UserId (uid) with custom UserId (int).
5. ...

On the one hand I like the first solution as it is quite straightforward and is suggested in an official asp.net tutorial.

On the other hand opponents note quite reasonably that using foreign keys breaks the general idea of providers which are supposed to help separating concerns and to be interchangeable. But unfortunately they do not go much into implementation details so it is not really easy to estimate those suggestions in terms of relevance and ease of implementation.

So what is the best option to approach this? Furthermore how would the implementation look like?  Would it be enough to use just additional ADO.NET or LINQ etc code or is it worth implementing a custom Membership and/or Profile Provider?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is the simpliest approach. Add the GUID of the user as a foreignkey in the related tables (f.e. Ordered_by). I don't see where it breaks separating concerns. If you want to keep the order-record in database, you also have to keep the user who has ordered, that makes perfectly sense.

I have used option 4 successfully in my current application. I've created a table `aspnet_UserID` with `idUser int` as primary-key and fiUser(the GUID of the `aspnet_Users`) as foreign-key. Here is the model:

[image: Data-Model]

(Note: `User` is the standard `aspnet_Users` table created via [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms229862%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and `aspnet_UserId` is my custom table that maps every Guid with my int-ID)

Now i'm storing only my `idUser` as FK in all related tables (like in your Order-Table). That has the advantage of less storage and more readable UserID's(i could never remember a GUID). Maybe it's somewhat more separated with this "wrapper-table" but that was not my main intention.

You can change the [delete-rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177288.aspx) on your foreignkeys if you want to control the behavior. Set it to `Cascade` if you f.e. want to delete all orders that were ordered by the user you're deleting or set it to `no Action` if you want to keep this order.

I can't suggest any alternatives for the Profile question because you haven't mentioned what you mean with "need to store and access user profile data in more flexible manner then the Profile provider supports".

Comment: Thank you for you answer, the 4th option looks really interesting. So you think that **SQL Membership Provider** (+ a bit of custom data access code) is **enough** for this scenario and the need to implement the custom **Profile Provider depends** on my particular requirements to the profile data, did I get it right?

Comment: @Kirill: as far as i can tell without knowing your exact requirements, Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider writing your own custom membership provider that uses the tables/data as per your need (instead of using ASP.NET provided schema).

See this MSDn sample ([schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx), [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx)) for writing a custom provider - this sample uses   OLEDB to access database. Yet another sample is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx) - it uses active directory as a store.