# Beginning ASP.NET. using login name as sql parameter

Tags: asp.net, authentication, parameter-passing, session-cookies

Does anyone have some code or a link as to how to create the user login name as a parameter during a sql query in ASP.NET?

Basically I want to use the default membership structure with a new field `ClubID`, then I want to add a new table called `aspnet_Clubs` which contains things such as Club Name, stadium name, Balance etc etc...  and then use a relationship between `ClubID` and a field in the `aspnet_Clubs` table to tie things together.

Then when each user logs in they should see the clubs information specific to their `loginID`.

I know the syntax to use for the query, its getting the `loginname` parameter and being able to use/assign it as part of the search that is causing me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not recommended to break the default schema of the aspnetdb where the Membership data is stored. It can bring you to unexpected consequences in the future.

I had a similar question a couple of days ago, please check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532418/how-to-combine-using-membership-api-with-own-application-related-data), may be you will be able to adopt something from the discussion to your situation.