# asp.net web application project template Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I would like to use the built-in membership / authentication system that is included by default in Visual Studio when creating a new asp.net web application.

My question is I have a user table... UserID, FirstName, LastName, etc. with company info that I want to use. How do I go about linking this table to the new registration I created?

Suppose I created a new registration. Now where is the login and password data being stored?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: FYI, "ASP.NET" is one word, with no spaces.

Comment: Are you using standard [SqlMembership-Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)? http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial can be very helpful at the beginning: [Creating the Membership Schema in SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs).

If you have basically only user profile information in your existing company database, may be you'll need to consider creating a [custom Profile Provider](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-profile-provider). Be aware that doing it while using the Web Application Project has its [perculiarities](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx).

If you have also other information in your database linked to user by foreing keys, may be you'll be interested in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532418/how-to-combine-using-membership-api-with-own-application-related-data) on how to use it with Membership.

Answer (score 2):

The membership info is stored in a SQL database ASPNETDB.MDF by default. You can find this file in your App_data folder.

If you want to change the way membership behaves, and which database and tables it uses I would recommend creating a custom membership provider.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx or google asp.net custom membership provider:

If you just want the existing membership provider to use a different database you can run the aspnet_regsql utility:

See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx

This example of a custom membership provider that uses entity framework codefirst helped me to get started:

http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

My humble suggestion is that you simply create a seperate table and relate it to your user table with a realtionship. So there is no change about where the login and password are stored.

This article might help you : http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs . Take a look at it.

Additional Articles:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020114106/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110310-1.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies, you all gave me some insight to help me figure out my problem. 
I decided to take an easier route.

This is what I came up with. In Register.aspx.cs:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox txtFirstName = (TextBox)(RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("txtFirstName "));
    string firstName= txtFirstName.Text;

    ... Insert new fields  in database ....

}
```

And added the controls in the CreateUserWizard control. Pretty simple solution.