# Can I add a foreign key to aspnet_Users table?

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing a website similar to Amazon. Each user can open a shop.

Thus the database has a `Shop` table, whose primary key is id. Each user can open at most one shop.

I know I can use `Profile Provider`. I have been already using it to save the user's address, telephones, and that sort of information. But I think saving shop id to Profile is not a good idea, because I can not use SQL to find out the shop owner's name of a given shop, which makes that I can not use the off-the-shelf data controls without code-behind to complete my function on the shop page.

So can I modify `aspnet_Users` table adding a `shop` field which is a foreign key to `Shop` table? Will it cause problems?

Or I built another `User` table and put `shop` field in it?

Or do you have any best practice of doing that sort of things?

Comment: Create a relation-table with FKs `ShopID` and `UserID`. You can either use the standard GUID or use an int wrapper. For the latter see my answer on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532418/how-to-combine-using-membership-api-with-own-application-related-data/6532611#6532611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't touch** `aspnet_Users`. It's managed by ASP.NET's membership provider, it might be changed in the future, lots of views and stored procedures touch it etc.

I recommend saving all profile data in a distinct table(s) and that's including name, address, whatever. That would also include each user's `ShopID` (as a one-to-one relationship, I think it's preferable, although you can do as @Tim suggested with many-to-many).

Comment: Why do not you prefer to use Profile provider in this scenario? Or when will you use it?

Comment: I had some bad experience with Profile provider. The default profile provider persists the users' data in an awful, non-queryable way. So if you go in that direction, you should at least implement another profile provider that uses more SQL-ish scheme. For example: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-profile-provider .

But I think it's better to roll your own profile table(s) in which the User Id is taken from ASP.NET Membership provider, and hence it's functioning as a foreign key and not primary key.

Comment: It helped. But I hear the login controls only operate with stored procedures. I have already decided to modify the table and just wait to see if any problems will happen.